# Two detailed views on the same page?

Tags: angular, typescript, express, routes

I have a component that has an ngFor directive looping through an array of users and another ngFor directive inside of that one looping through all of the posts a user is making.  I have a view link within this element rendering my two ngFor loops, I want to be able to click this view link and see a detailed view of the user and the post in question.  However I am unsure if this is even possible.  Right now the view link works, it takes me to the page and shows the user and the listing item, the problem is that when you click on the next item in the list to view the details of it, either the user is wrong or the post in question is wrong.  In my routing I have one route that goes to the page I want to display both detailed views on ending in :/..  in the component that lists the users and their posts I have the view link that looks like this.

```
<a mat-button routerLinkActive [routerLink]="['/city-care/view-request/', request.id]">View</a>.
```

Is it possible to make it where when the user clicks this link they get the detailed view of the request it is associated with as well as the proper user?  Right now I am navigating by request and the snapshot of the route works for only the request.  How would I go about accomplishing this task? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

My list component

```
    <mat-accordion multi="true" *ngIf ="!isLoading && userIsAuthenticated">

  <h3>All User Requests</h3>

  <mat-expansion-panel class='panel' *ngFor="let user of users">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header *ngIf="user.requests.length > 0"> 
      <mat-panel-title>
        <p>Name:&nbsp; {{ user.first_name }}&nbsp;{{ user.last_name }}</p>
      </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-description  *ngFor="let request of user.requests">
      <p class='left-align'>Request: &nbsp;{{ request.name }} <br>
      {{request.details}}</p>
      <div class="col sm6 right-align">
        <a mat-button routerLinkActive [routerLink]="['/city-care/view-request/', request.id, 

    user.id]">View</a>
          </div>
        </mat-panel-description>
      </mat-expansion-panel>
    </mat-accordion>
```

My detailed view component.

```
 <div *ngIf="request && user && !isLoading && userIsAuthenticated">
      <div class="card">
        Contact Person: {{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}} <br>
      Email: &nbsp; {{ user.email }} <br>
      Phone: &nbsp; {{ user.phone }} <br>
      Mobile: &nbsp; {{ user.mobile_phone }} <br>
      <hr>
      Need: &nbsp; {{ request.name }} <br>
      Details: &nbsp; {{ request.details }}<br>
      Date Needed: &nbsp; {{ request.needByDate | date }} <br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col sm6 right-align">
      <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn back" routerLink="/city-care/site- 
      postings">Back</button>&nbsp;

    
    </div>
```

here is my route

```
{ path: 'city-care/view-request/:id', component: ViewRequestComponent, canActivate: [ AuthGuard 
 ] },
```

Inside of the detailed view component ts file I am calling on the route snapshot to view the details, how can achieve the desired outcome of displaying both the users details and the request in questions details on the same page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a service to get the user data of the request in the detailed view component. Can you do that?

In `ViewRequestComponent` you can inject a service that knows all about Users. Inside the `ngOnInit` function, you could get the user from the request. Like the example from the angular documentation: https://angular.io/guide/router#accessing-query-parameters-and-fragments

```
ngOnInit() {
  const requestId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
  this.user = this.userService.getUserByRequestId(requestId)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to have the following structure

1. A `HomeComponent`
2. A `Component` to shows a `card` of the users information
3. A `Component` that shows a `card` of the general post
4. A `Component` that shows the details of posts.

In the `HomeComponent` using `*ngFor` renders all users. e.g. show 10 card which each card display **firstName**, **LastName**, and **Avatar** of each users (route: **http://localhost:4200/users**). By Clicking on each card of users we will navigate to another component that using a `*ngFor` shows a list of all users posts. for example showing 10 card which each one shows **title** of posts. (route: **http://localhost:4200/users/12**). Then by Clicking on each posts the component of details of each post will be rendered. (route: **http://localhost:4200/users/12/13**).

So your route config will be something like this:

```js
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'users', component: UserComponent },
  { path: 'users/:id', component: PostComponent },
  { path: 'users/:id/:id2', component: PostDetailsComponent }
];
```

Comment: Right. Ordinarily that is what I would have done.  However I am trying to find a work around where I don't have to revamp the entire project to do this.